# Google Drive "Sorry, an error occurred when opening this file. Please try again."

Tags: google-drive-api

I've built a web app integrated with google drive sdk. Since a few days ago users can no longer open files by clicking on the file name in the Drive Web app, and instead are getting the message "Sorry, an error occurred when opening this file. Please try again.". I'd really appreciate a pointer in the right direction for how to resolve this.

Both API access and Drive SDK are enabled in the API console for the project. Everything works OK with a right click -> open with -> selecting the application. Everything works OK when people access files from my application directly.

When I right click on a file and look for authorized applications, no apps are listed. I've tried changing the application OAuth settings to request more permissive access, no luck. This leads me to believe that the authorization is OK, but some config is wrong for the google drive UI. I'm not sure if it was caused by me or some environment change, but none of the URLs or config changed between people being able to open files on click and getting the error.

Google product forums seem to suggest that this happens for large files (>2MB), but our files are only a few KB, so this does not seem to be the cause. Googling around for related problems, I could not find anything useful.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to look for more info? Drive pages suggest this is the place to ask for help. Or, alternatively, is there a way to get commercial support from the Google drive people monitoring this tag? I've wasted too much time on this already and I'm happy to pay for some help.

Comment: You seem to be affected by a bug on Google side that should be fixed on Monday. Because of this bug, left clicking on a file to open it with a third-party app installed as default app for that type is not working correctly.

Comment: Hi Claudio - thanks, it seems to have been fixed meanwhile

Comment: I would guess the file has some unsupported resource by google who can't then properly convert it to google docs. Maybe a different font or something included (or not included) within it. `Doc` is a terrible, terrible standard. Try copy and paste.

Comment: It seems that Monday have long been overdue.